# Redirect all http AND https non-www URLS to https://www.xyz.com via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, https

For reasons much too long and complex to get into (it involves several layers of corporate red tape resulting in someone else not purchasing a wildcard SSL certificate I requested), I have to set up a domain to redirect all requests to https://www.xyz.com – secure protocol with the `www` subdomain.

So: http://xyz.com, http://www.xyz.com, and https://xyz.com should ALL redirect to https://www.xyz.com.

My .htaccess-fu is weak at best and I can't seem to get this to work. Note: hosting is on Media Temple if that makes a difference.

So far, my .htaccess file looks like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.xyz.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Both http://xyz.com and http://www.xyz.com are redirecting to https://www.xyz.com, so yay. However, https://xyz.com is *not* redirecting to https://www.xyz.com and is thus throwing a security warning page:

> **This is probably not the site you are looking for!**
>
>   You attempted to reach **xyz.com**, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as **www.xyz.com**. This may be caused by a misconfiguration on the server or by something more serious. An attacker on your network could be trying to get you to visit a fake (and potentially harmful) version of **xyz.com**.
>   You should not proceed, especially if you have never seen this warning before for this site.

Any help in getting me past this one final hump would be muchly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case anyone from the future (HELLO PEOPLE OF THE FUTURE) stumble across this, I asked the same question and had it answered over at Server Fault.

Short version: impossible.

Long version: https://serverfault.com/questions/523199/redirect-all-http-and-https-non-www-urls-to-https-www-example-com-via-htaccess

Answer (score 9):

This is very much possible. use the following code. this works for me.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}$1
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, because I didn't have my certificate enabled for both www.mydomain.com AND mydomain.com per the answer from Scottie.

Answer (score 3):

Even though this issue is very old.

If found it googeling the exact same issue. After the Code provided here didn't help. I tried and tried.

This one worked for me:

```
     RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
     RewriteRule .* https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
     RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
     RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
     RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
     RewriteRule .* https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Fixed the issue for me without any Loops or other errors. Maybe it will help someone else.

Comment: This solution has worked after about 20 minutes of trying many items, it's not perfect, but everything else directs non-http to https://www.www.example.com whcih I couldn't figure out!

Answer (score 0):

I sincerely do not understand [@scottie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102731/scottie) link saying IMPOSSIBLE being the accepted answer.

I am using below codes on 3 of my websites, [provided here](https://serverfault.com/questions/523199/redirect-all-http-and-https-non-www-urls-to-https-www-example-com-via-htaccess) by [Erik](https://serverfault.com/users/316657/eric-k) and it successfully makes
http://example.com, http://www.example.com, https://example.com all land on https://www.example.com

```
RewriteEngine On
# ensure www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

P.S: I had to `#RewriteEngine On` because I already have `RewriteEngine On` at the beginning of my `.htaccess`

I hope this also helps someone like me who might have thought its a really long process, and if by any chance there is a shortcoming of this I am not aware, kindly let me know.