# Use .htaccess to redirect HTTP to HTTPs

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, redirect, https

I have tried [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever), and many others ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489895/http-to-https-through-htaccess), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999910/https-to-http-redirect-using-htaccess), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638611/redirect-all-http-and-https-non-www-urls-to-https-www-xyz-com-via-htaccess)), but they all give me TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS or error 500. So, here is my issue:

With my current .htaccess, this is what happens:

https://www.dukescasino.com/ - works perfectly

https://dukescasino.com/ - redirects to the above which is great

The two options below loads fine, but it should be redirecting to the https version:

http://www.dukescasino.com/

http://dukescasino.com/

Here is the current .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I don't believe it is relevant, but if so, here is the list of current active plugins:

- Advanced Custom Fields
- All In One SEO Pack
- Bop Search Box Item Type For Nav Menus
- Contact Form 7
- Disable Comments
- Google XML Sitemaps
- Jetpack by WordPress.com
- Search & Filter
- Slider WD
- TablePress
- UpdraftPlus - Backup/Restore
- Wordfence Security
- WPide
- WP Smush
- WP Super Cache

**Tests performed:**

**Test A:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

*Result:* ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

**Test B:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
 
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

*Result:* ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

**Test C:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
 RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
 
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

*Result:* ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

**Test D:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

*Result:* ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

**Test E:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}$1

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

*Result:* 302 found. Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Maybe just a typo, but you have spelt `.htaccess` wrong (the same way) 3 times? Your current .htaccess file is not complete, you are missing a `RewriteEngine On` directive. Presumably, when you add the canonical redirect you are adding this to the very top of your .htaccess file? You state that `https://example.com` redirects OK, however, this is not indicated in your config file? Where/how is this happening? It would be useful to know what you have actually tried - that is not working.

Comment: Sorry, the .htaccess was a typo, I've fixed it now. I've also updated the current .htaccess code and all the test I've done with the result of each. I don't know how the https without www is redirecting to the https://www version though. Thanks

Comment: You would normally expect the server variable `HTTPS` to be set (your results suggest otherwise). Are you behind a proxy? (Test E is likely to result in some kind of "recursive" 404?)

Comment: I've just contacted 123-reg (hosting company) to check if they have anything set up on their side that is messing things up. Even if I have the working .htaccess and set up redirect tool inside their (123reg) control panel I get the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Problem solved!

Final .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This change resulted in "[www.domain.com] redirected you too many times" for a domain I host on Dreamhost. No luck.
However, this worked:

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Comment: I had to change just the `RewriteCond` to the following one to avoid the `too many redirects`: `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on`

Comment: For me on virtualmin apache 2.4 caused forbidden. The solution from @jason-shah worked.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. This solution redirects "you too many times." chrome says.

Comment: Just these 2 lines are added. Work great! Thanks..
`RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]`

Comment: @zhekaus you also have to change the values of 'siteurl' and 'home' options in wp_options table from http:// to https://

Comment: This is the only one solution that worked for me. (Tested far too many.) The "ENV:" was crucial. From the replies and other solutions, it seems that on some host you either **have to include** it while on others you **have  to leave it out**. BTW For anybody wanting to use this, consider using `R=301` instead of just `R` (which means 302 redirect).

Comment: The Above Code Results in "Error: Too many redirects"! Removing the ENV does the trick!

Answer (score 145):

On Dreamhost, this worked:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This one is worked for me on namecheap shared hosting.

Comment: Worked on asmallorange.com too

Comment: Worked for me on a LAMP server with Wordpress 4.7.4 on provider Time4VPS

Comment: Make sure to get the exact ordering of the rules correct. I had put the rewrite rule under the existing WordPress rules, but then only the root domain rerouted and not any HTTP URI requests. This correct ordering above the existing WordPress rules routes all HTTP requests properly.

Comment: There's no need to point out every single host that this works on! It's a straightforward bit of code for .htaccess so it should work on most system them accept .htaccess. If it doesn't work then it's because of an odd case scenario.

Comment: Working on shared hosting Godaddy just fine!

Comment: I'm gonna ignore Phill and point out it worked on 1and1 hosting.  You can't use the root directory htaccess with their cheap plan for some reason so this is the only option.

Comment: Thank you, it worked!
I'm using hostgator+wordpress v4.9.8+goDaddy

Answer (score 16):

It works for me:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on           
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 13):

In my case, the htaccess file contained lots of rules installed by plugins like **Far Future Expiration** and **WPSuperCache** and also the lines from wordpress itself.

In order to not mess things up, I had to put the solution at the top of htaccess (this is important, if you put it at the end it causes some wrong redirects due to conflicts with the cache plugin)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

This way, your lines don't get messed up by wordpress in case some settings change. Also, the **`<IfModule>`** section can be repeated without any problems.

I have to thank [Jason Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/449670/jason-shah) for the neat [htaccess rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36475195/531524).

Comment: This is essential information. Thanks for posting it!

Answer (score 4):

## This is tested and safe to use

Why?: When Wordpress **editing your re-write rules**, so make sure your **HTTPS rule should not be removed**! so this is **no conflict** with native Wordpress rules.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
   RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  #Your our Wordpress rewrite rules...
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**Note:** You have to change **WordPress Address** & **Site Address** urls to `https://` in **General Settings** also (`wp-admin/options-general.php`)

Comment: The WordPress part should go after the HTTPS one, or it won't work. Or, at least, this is what happened for me :)

Comment: Confirming what @Ste_95 said. I had to put the HTTPS rewrite block ahead of the default WP permalink config.

Answer (score 4):

For your information, it really depends on your hosting provider.

In my case ([Infomaniak](https://www.infomaniak.com)), nothing above actually worked and I got infinite redirect loop.

The right way to do this is [actually explained in their support site](https://www.infomaniak.com/en/support/faq/1961/redirecting-all-visitors-to-the-site-using-https-ssl):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule (.*) https://your-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So, always check with your hosting provider. Hopefully they have an article explaining how to do this. Otherwise, just ask the support.

Answer (score 1):

I found all solutions listed on this Q&A did not work for me, unfortunately. What did work was:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/" [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# End Wordpress
```

Note, the above Wordpress rules are for Wordpress in multi user network mode. If your Wordpress is in single site mode, you would use:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/" [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# End Wordpress
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing of the above worked for me. But those lines solved the same problem on my WordPress site:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

easyest way to redirect http to https in **wordpress** it to modify site_url and home from http://example.com to https://example.com. Wordpress will do the redirection. ( that is why you get "too many redirects" error, wordpress is redirecting to http while .htaccess will redirect to https )

Comment: I'm not sure it does any redirection for SEO :)

Comment: sure it does. redirection 301 ( permanent ), google will reindex

Comment: Keep in mind that this is not working with Google Search Console!

Comment: it will work just fine.... wordpress will do a redirection (301). keep in mind this: rtfm

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution you can use if you don't want to edit `.htaccess`:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'nonhttps_template_redirect', 1 );

function nonhttps_template_redirect() {

    if ( is_ssl() ) {

        if ( 0 === strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'https' ) ) {

            wp_redirect( preg_replace( '|^http://|', 'https://', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ), 301 );

            exit();

        } else {

            wp_redirect( 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 301 );

            exit();

        }

    }

}
```

You can place this at the bottom of your theme `functions.php`

Comment: Not entirely sure yet, my guess is it will remain the same depending on the reason Google might have index it as the HTTPS version to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the WordPress' .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursite.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yoursite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yoursite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Therefore the default WordPress' .htaccess file should look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursite.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yoursite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yoursite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above final .htaccess and Test A,B,C,D,E did not work for me. I just used below 2 lines code and it works in my WordPress website:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.thehotskills.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I'm not sure where I was making the mistake but this page helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^digitalsoftwaremarket.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.digitalsoftwaremarket.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

None if this worked for me. First of all I had to look at my provider to see how they activate SSL in `.htaccess` my provider gives

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTPS} !on
   RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

But what took me days of research is I had to add to `wp-config.php` the following lines as my provided site is behind a proxy :

```
/**
 * Force le SSL
 */
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false) $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add or replace this code in your .htaccess file in wordpress

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirect from http to https://www

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

This will work for sure!

Answer (score -1):

Just add this code, And it will work like charm:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}#%{HTTPS}s ^www\.([^#]+)#(?:off|on(s)) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http%2://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```