# Use web.config to redirect HTTP to HTTPs

Tags: wordpress, redirect, ssl, iis

I have installed WordPress on my IIS server and I also have the SSL Certificate installed.

I have researched every thread I could find on this, but still couldn't get it work. I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32049820/use-htaccess-to-redirect-http-to-https) from a guy on Apache who is facing the same issue, but I am on IIS and don't know how to get it to work with IIS.

Similar to that thread, here is what is happening:

`https://www.example.com` is working great

`https://example.com` is redirecting to the above, also great!

Here is the problem:

`http://www.example.com` is still accessible, no good, as this should redirect to `https://www.example.com`

Also:

`http://example.com` redirects to `http://www.example.com`.

How can I fix this, so that it all redirects to `https://www.example.com`?

I am on IIS and here is what my `web.config` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Did you try [this](https://gist.github.com/tkarpinski/1621178)?

Comment: Will I add that rule in addition to the rule that already exists? If yes, does that new rule go before or after?

Comment: Last time I tried, all images on my site broke, I went ahead anyway and it worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Dan, this worked.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
        <rules>
      <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would like to suggest you to get extension called “[URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)” on your IIS.

Then you should match your code with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="HTTP/S to HTTPS Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
          <add input="{SERVER_PORT_SECURE}" pattern="^1$" />
          <add input="{SERVER_PORT_SECURE}" pattern="^0$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/OWA/" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```