# wordpress http to https redirect not working

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, https

I am trying to redirect my wordpress site from http to https. My wordpress site is on EC2 Instance and I followed this link for [link for redirection](https://www.davidmeents.com/blog/add-ssl-ec2-wordpress-instance-use-https/)

I am able to see the https working, but however the default redirection from http to https is not happening. Like if I go to http://testwordpress.com it should get redirected to https://testwordpress.com

I followed most of the answers [from this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083221/how-to-redirect-all-http-requests-to-https/21798882), but nothing seemed to be working for me

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://testwordpress.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The below code gives me 503 error code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} !^testwordpress.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://testwordpress.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: can you show us how you coded your redirection?

Comment: @Kaddath I updated my question.

Comment: You need to include `[OR]` on your first condition in the code that gives you a 503. So `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]`

Comment: @Lag Can you please expand your explanation.

Comment: Why not use a plugin such as [WP Force SSL](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-force-ssl/)

Comment: Where have you placed this code? Any mod_rewrite directives after the WP front controller is not going to work as intended. When you say "the below code gives me 503", have you also _removed_ the code above, immediately below the WP front controller? Otherwise you will certainly get an error. (But a 503 is unusual here.)

Comment: Please check [http to https redirect solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32049820/use-htaccess-to-redirect-http-to-https/50563575#50563575) this . Its already solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To force HTTPs using `.htaccess` all you need to use is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Place this at the top of your `.htaccess` file and make sure you clear your cache **before** testing this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update wordpress database. Try update `wp_options` first.

`UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';`

`UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl'); UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl');`

`UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');`

Comment: This is the first step I did for redirection.

Comment: @PrabhuKhannaMahadevan did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32049820/use-htaccess-to-redirect-http-to-https

Answer (score 0):

## Permanent URL redirect

```
// Add following code in htaccess

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
Redirect 301 / https://testwordpress.com
</IfModule>
```

Make sure you have entered https in backend:

```
WordPress Address (URL)     
Site Address (URL)
```

OR

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# Rewrite HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{testwordpress.com}/$1 [R,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: https is added in the backend. Still the same 503 Error.