# Wordpress not redirecting to HTTPS

Tags: wordpress, apache, redirect, https

I'm currently working on a new Wordpress Site and (ofc) want to redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS. They way I tried it is by defining this in my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

For the landingpage this works fine, but all posts are still accessible through HTTP without getting redirected. Any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: is the permalinks "default" permalinks or "post type" in permalinks page?

Comment: you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32049820/use-htaccess-to-redirect-http-to-https

Answer (score 0):

Appareantly the order of the configs is important. When placing is at the very top of the `.htaccess` it worked as expected.

Comment: Please do not post comments as answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here, There are a couple different options you have when choosing to redirect HTTP to HTTPS in WordPress.

- **Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Nginx**

**E.g.** Method for redirecting WordPress running on Nginx.

```html
server {
listen 80;
server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

- **Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache**

**E.g.** Method for redirecting WordPress running on Apache.

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

- **Redirect HTTP to HTTPS with Really Simple SSL Plugin**

**E.g.** The third option you have to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS is to use the free WordPress [Really Simple SSL plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/).