# htaccess can't load vegas slide login background

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, .htaccess

After modify `.htaccess` for redirect http to https, I get a problem on the background login that can't load.

This is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

and this my vegas slide login background :

```
<script src="http://zeptojs.com/zepto.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{asset('admin/assets/plugins/vegas/vegas.min.js') }}"></script>
<script>
    $("body").vegas({
        slides: [
            { src: "{{asset('admin/assets/images/login_background/5.jpg') }}" },
            { src: "{{asset('admin/assets/images/login_background/6.jpg') }}" },
            { src: "{{asset('admin/assets/images/login_background/7.jpg') }}" },
            { src: "{{asset('admin/assets/images/login_background/8.jpg') }}" }
        ],
        overlay: true
    });
</script>
```

somebody please help me to solved my problem.
thanks

Comment: maybe this could help. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32049820/use-htaccess-to-redirect-http-to-https

Comment: Most likely the issue simply is that you have a hard coded http reference in your code. Please read about the security model modern browsers implement and follow for very good reasons: they will block any attempt to make a http request from within a document loaded via https. Would will actually see that issue if you open your browsers development console and check the networking tab in there.